# Add Facebook Share Button on IP Board

Tags: javascript, php, html, share

I want to Add Facebok **Share Button** on My IP Board 3.4.5 Forum

I try to use the integrated way in ip board, but its not seem to work.

I tried several ways, include this one:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button_count" expr:share_url="data:post.canonicalUrl" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but cant find somthing that working properly on my forum. Each post it gives an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show us what error you get?

Comment: It seems to work now. dont know why.